# Formal Model of Immutability

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, binary-operations, type-theory

Wondering if there is a formal model / algebra / etc. of [immutability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). This comes up in functional programming with [*persistent data structures*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure), but I haven't seen any pure math related to it.

For example, given an operation $\circ$ and two sets $A$ and $B$, then $A \circ B = C$. But if you wanted to "undo" $C$, there might not be enough information in $C$ to get back to $A$ unless $C$ preserved the structure of $A$ and $B$. It is preserved in persistent data structures, which got me wondering if there is a formal model for it.

Comment: It is more of a challenge to introduce the notion of _mutability_, rather than the inverse.

Answer (score 1):

In mathematics, objects are immutable by definition in any given context. However, if you define $\;x=3\;$ in one context, then you can define $\;x=1\;$ in some other context, but it is immutable in any given context. Of course, variables may have more than one value, or else none. This is **not** mutability though. The concept of indexed object is perhaps what you mean. That is, for example, $\;a_0=1,\; a_n=2a_{n-1}\;$ is an indexed object which changes with the index. Of course, $\;a_n=1\;$ for all $\;n\;$ is a constant object which does not change with the index.

As for your idea of "undo", all that involves is operations having an inverse. Some operations have inverses and others don't. For example, $\;A+B=C\;$ can be "undone" by $\;A=C-B.\;$ This is an important property of addition as a group operation, but in general, you can't "undo" operations.

When you switch from the mathematical realm to the realm of reality, then things are very different. This is only natural. Different rules apply to different realms. As [Heraclitus](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Heraclitus) stated "everything changes" (in Greek). Constrast this with [Plato's  immutable, ideal Forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_forms). These are perrenial philosophical issues.

However, even the Greeks were able to "model" the movment of some heavenly bodies. Thus, in mathematics there is the study of "dynamical systems" which studies the properties of models of changing systems. Thus, in this sense, you can develop models of mutable and [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), but in the context of programming langues. Perhaps this is what you mean.

Comment: The addition example doesn't work outside of numbers. Say for example $A$ is car and $B$ is paint. We can say we start with a red car $a_r \in A$, and green paint $b_g \in B$. If we do $a_r + b_g = a_g$ we get a green car. Now we do $a_g - b_g$ we _don't_ get a red car. We get an unknown colored car. That is because _addition was mutable_. This is what I'm wondering about the study of immutability. Immutability preserves the history of the operation.

Comment: You misunderstand mathematics here. Your "car" and "paint" are not mathematical objects. And, yes, the addition example **does** work outside of numbers in the context of groups where the group operation is explictly required to have an inverse.

Comment: Further to what @Somos wrote, in mathematics, we don't usually talk of *operations* as being mutable. It's true that (for example) in an OOP context, one might have a method on an *object* that mutates that object: if `a` is an `Int` object, there might be a method `plus` such that `a.plus(b)` changes the contents of `a` to the value of 'a + b'; but that's an implementation detail of a specific OOP system.

Comment: If you're interested in algebraic structures that have an inverse operation, in addition to groups as already mentioned by @Somos, check out the [inverse element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_element) entry on Wikipedia.